# Make a div's height matches its parent div's height which is set auto

Tags: css

This is really simple, yet I don't know how to solve this

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width:500px; background:black;">
            <div style="display:inline-block; width:200px; height:300px; background:yellow;"></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: top; width:100px; height:100%; background:pink;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QG572/4/)

I want the pink div's height matches the black div's which is set auto.

Edit: actually I want to match the pink height to the yellow one so that the black's height matches the yellow's also.

Comment: If you set body to `height:100%` it is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position:absolute` could be an answer.

```
<html style="height:100%;">

    <body style="height:auto;position:relative;">
        <div style="width:500px; height:100%; background:black;">
            <div style="display:inline-block; width:200px; height:300px; background:yellow;"></div>
            <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: top; width:100px; height:100%; background:pink;position:absolute;
left:100px;
margin-left:0.25em;
top:0;
bottom:0;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QG572/2/

Or use `display:table` to keep everything in the flow:

```
<html style="height:100%;">

    <body style="">
        <div style="width:500px; height:100%;display:table; background:black;">
            <div style="display:table-cell; width:200px; height:300px; background:yellow;"></div>
            <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align: top; width:100px; height:100%; background:pink;"></div>
            <div style="display:table-cell;"><!-- to fill 100px left--></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QG572/3/

Comment: in both case , height on body and the black div is unecessary , the fiddle are quick and dirty updates :)

Comment: from IE8, below as does this absolute sizing method, below you need a fall back with float and javascript to get the height of the higest container

Comment: I don't understand why didn't the developers of css implement this in earlier development. This is so simple yet they made it so complicated and hard to understand. What's so hard about making a component's height matches its parent's dynamic height? Thanks a lot GCyrillus!

Comment: display:table; was avalaible since 1998 in CSS2 but IE6 was around for almost a decade (a lifetime), on almost every computer, it's only after FF did show up that microsoft woke up ... and finally came up with IE8 ...

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height in the wrapper div and letting the children containers inherit the height is could work for you.

html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="black">
            <div class="yellow"></div>
            <div class="pink"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    .black{
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        background: black;
    }
    .black div {
         display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        height: inherit;
    }

    .yellow{
        background: yellow;
    }
    .pink {
        background: pink;
    }
```